# Formatting options in Telegraph

Tags: format, telegram, monospace, telegraph, telegra.ph

I want to use `monospaced` format in Telegraph, just like I just did, not a block of code, just a single word. Also I'd like some strike-through too. Those are formatting options available in most (if not all) Telegram apps, and my purpose is to move some large posts to Telegraph pages. But those formats are not available in [telegra.ph](https://telegra.ph). **Or are they?** I've noted that the hidden underline format is available by using the intuitive Ctrl+U shortcut, but that's the only one I've found so far.

[image: Formatting options available in telegra.ph]

It is possible use `monospace` format in [telegra.ph](https://telegra.ph)? If not, then I must code the content manually.

If the latter, the [Telegraph API](https://telegra.ph/api#NodeElement) states the following:

> **tag (String)**
>
> Name of the DOM element. Available tags: *a*, *aside*, *b*, *blockquote*, *br*, *code*, *em*, *figcaption*, *figure*, *h3*, *h4*, *hr*, *i*, *iframe*, *img*, *li*, *ol*, *p*, *pre*, *s*, *strong*, *u*, *ul*, *video*.

I don't know if there are any tag that can represent a `monospaced` word or text because I don't know what many of them are for.

Answer (score 3):

**Update!**
You can try the following:

Go to the next line and try entering ```

---

This can be done by using the `pre` tag. However, I'm not sure if it's possible to do this with the in-house `telegra.ph` tool. From the documentation:

> NodeElement This object represents a DOM element node.
>
> tag (String) Name of the DOM element. Available tags: a, aside, b,
> blockquote, br, code, em, figcaption, figure, h3, h4, hr, i, iframe,
> img, li, ol, p, pre, s, strong, u, ul, video.

[Telegra.ph API](https://telegra.ph/api#NodeElement)

Comment: The `pre` tag adds a block of code, but it works with the `code` tag. However, as you pointed out, the `telegraph.ph` tool does not have a way to do that, so I edited the content manually by using the browser's development tools. Thanks for the answer anyways.